# Complex Mongoose findOneAndUpdate query not working looking for specific advice

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a somewhat complex Mongoose query I want to make and while I can find the different parts around the internet (including here) I can't seem to find exactly what I need and piecing the existing info together has not worked so I am looking for specific how to do this.

I want to findOneAndUpdate to add data to blockSection array in my document.

```
Block.findOneAndUpdate({
        section: {$elemMatch: {section_code: sectionID}}
    },
    {"$push": {blockSection.section: blocSecData}},  // blocSecData is defined elsewhere and is an object
    (err, result) => {
        if(err) {
            return res.json({success: false, err})
        }
        ... // more code here to processstuff
    })
```

Rough example of a sample Block with only one item per array

```
{
  "section_code":"<abc>",
  "blockSection": [
    {
      section: [{"text":"hello world"}], // add the data here
      "_id":"<foobar>",
      "blockSecID":"<a uuid>"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What part does not work? Finding or updating?

Comment: @NenadMilosavljevic I'm not really sure, it just returns an empty object as the error and nothing else.

Comment: Can you add the whole Schema model?

Comment: @NenadMilosavljevic Uhh.. I'd rather not as I don't think I can share it without issues. As it is I had to change some stuff in the OP to make it not clear what this was.

Comment: Ok, tell me this. Your original collection have `section` field which is array with properties above? Or is your sample from above the actual model?

Comment: @NenadMilosavljevic `section` field is an array defined in the model as an array and as a required value. No defaults or anything. The above example object is a query of the DB and stripped down to only have a few parts in it to make it simpler to understand than a ~70 field model

Comment: I guess essentially the question would boil down to, I need to find and update a document in MongoDB which has an array of objects which contain an ID field and another array. I want to use that ID field and push onto the array within the same object

Comment: Your `blockSection` field is an array. You want to push into the first item of it or another item with some condition?

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc Yes it is an array and I want to push into the section array not the blockSection array

Comment: In your code I see `section_code` is a field of item in section array, is that correct?

Comment: And your Block also has `section_code` field. Which one do you want to query with?